# SQL Server grouping by weeks but only capturing the max date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

## Some screenshots of what I'm trying to do:

[What is returning from my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKd7X.png)

[Claim No 456 with multiple service from dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OOjY.png)

[What is returning with my current code for claim No 456](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhF9k.png)

[This is the return I am hoping for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG7kP.png)

## Explanation:

I work with claims processing in the healthcare industry and I am trying to compile a report based on service from dates and received dates.

I am counting claim numbers by service from dates vs date received and grouping the dates received and service from dates by weeks. However, for someone receiving physical therapy they may have multiple service dates within a month. So it is recounting the claim number every week.

Is it possible to only count the claim number once by its last service from date? I do not want claim No 456 to be counted three times, one for each separate week.

## Here's what I have so far:

```
Select
    Dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, service_fromdate),0) as dos,
    Count(distinct claim_no) as no_claims,
    Dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, date_received),0) as rec
From
    Claims_table
Where
    CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, service_fromdate, 101) as date time) >= '07/01/2016'
Group by
    Dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, service_fromdate),0),
    Dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, date_received),0)
```

---

Thank you for your time.

Comment: what data types are service_fromdate and date_received, are they datetime fields in your table?

Comment: Yes, they are all date time data types

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected output please? There's data that I can't see in your example which is throwing things off.

Comment: Claim no 456, may have service from date 7/1/2016  and service from date 7/15/2016 and service from date 7/30/2016 but the received date will only be one date e.g 8/1/2016.  So, what I would like is to capture the the claim number count (that 1 claim) for that received date but only for its last service from date attached to claim. So that claim count would only fall within its last service from date by week. My current code is capturing that claim 3 times since it has 3 different service from dates. I only want it to capture it once for its last service from date.  Does that help clarify?

Comment: Using the 1 claim example above I would like a return of service from date (grouped by week as Monday as the first) 7/25/2016, count of claims 1, date received 8/1/2016.  With my code the claim is counted for 3 different service from dates and returning the same received date.

Comment: I added some screenshots to help clarify what my query is currently returning, an example of what claim no 456 will look like, and what I would like it to return. Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: Use text instead of images. Try reading this question on a phone and you will quickly realize why. Additionally if the sample data is in reuasble text it can be used in sample solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, write the query as:

```
Select dos, Count(distinct claim_no) as no_claims, rec
From Claims_table c cross apply
     (values (Dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, service_fromdate),0),
              Dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, date_received),0)
             )
     ) v(dos, rec)
where service_fromdate >= '2016-07-01'
Group by dos, rec;
```

The `cross apply` makes the query much easier to read.  This also fixes the logic in the `where` clause.  I really doubt that you want a string comparison with values larger than `'07/01/2016'`.

Then, to do what you want, you need the first record.  I think this is what you want:

```
Select dos, Count(claim_no) as no_claims, rec
From (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by claim_no order by service_fromdate desc) as seqnum
      from Claims_table c
     ) c cross apply
     (values (Dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, service_fromdate),0),
              Dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, date_received),0)
             )
     ) v(dos, rec)
where seqnum = 1 and service_fromdate >= '2016-07-01'
Group by dos, rec;
```

Note that `count(distinct)` is no longer necessary, because the claims should only appear one time.

Comment: It did not seem to be working for me. I must have not asked my question correctly. I provided some examples of what I need it to do.

Comment: @KevinK I made a couple of tweaks to the code, it should now match the sample output you provided.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for helping me with this.  Is cast covert poor logic?

Comment: @KevinK sorry, it seems no one has approved my edit yet. I added `desc` to `order by service_fromdate desc` and a `-1` to `datediff (week, 0, service_fromdate)-1`

Comment: @mendosi . . . I didn't see an edit pending, but I did make the change.

Comment: So to capture the minimum date I would order the ow_number() over (partition by claim_no order by service_fromdate desc) as seqnum to ASC?

Comment: @KevinK . . . Yes, you would change the sort order.